# Problems with C++ Pointers, Iterator, Adjacency List Representation of Graph

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I had a previous post: ["Trouble with List or Pointers,..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810806/trouble-with-list-or-pointers-adjacency-representaiton-of-graph) and received some very helpful information about pointers. After implementing the changes with better understanding, I still have some very strange behaviour:

Two vertices are created, and then an undirected edge between them. Each vertex has a list of pointers to the edges that are incident upon it. With this graph, the edge count should not be 0. But in the process of counting edges, I see that I'm getting different locations for my edgelist, which may explain my counting problem.

Here is a brief readout from couts:

The address of vertex 1's list: 0x1851018
The address of vertex 2's list: 0x1851038

At Vertex 1 we have...
The address of the edge list is... 0x1851068

At Vertex 2 we have...
The address of the edge list is... 0x1851098

```
#include "MinCut.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct undirected_edge;
class vertex;

struct undirected_edge
{
    vertex * start;
    vertex * end;
};

class vertex
{
    int vertexLabel;
    std::list<undirected_edge*> edgeList;
public:
    int getVertexNumber(){return vertexLabel;}
    std::list<undirected_edge*> * getPointerOfEdgeList(){
        std::cout << vertexLabel << " has edge List at: " << &edgeList << "\n";
    return &edgeList;}

    vertex(int n){vertexLabel=n;}
};


class undirected_graph
{
private:
    std::list<vertex>  graph;

public:
    void addVertex(vertex * v){graph.push_back(*v);}
    void createEdge(vertex * v1, vertex * v2);
    undirected_edge * getRandomEdge();
    void removeEdge(undirected_edge * e);
    int getNumberOfNodes(){return graph.size();}
    int getNumberOfEdges();
};
void buildGraph(undirected_graph *);

void undirected_graph::createEdge(vertex * v1, vertex * v2)
{
    std::list<undirected_edge*> * e1 = v1->getPointerOfEdgeList();
    std::list<undirected_edge*> * e2 = v2->getPointerOfEdgeList();
    undirected_edge * e = new undirected_edge;
    e->start=v1;
    e->end=v2;
    e1->push_back(e);
    e2->push_back(e);
    std::cout<< "The address of vertex 1's list: " << e1 << "\n";
    std::cout<< "The address of vertex 2's list: " << e2 << "\n";
}

int undirected_graph::getNumberOfEdges()
{    
    int size = getNumberOfNodes();
    std::list<vertex>::iterator it = graph.begin();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"At Vertex " << it->getVertexNumber() << " we have...\n";
        std::cout<<"The address of the edge list is... " << it->getPointerOfEdgeList() << "\n";
        counter = counter + it->getPointerOfEdgeList()->size();
        std::cout<<it->getPointerOfEdgeList()->size()<<"\n";
        it++;
    }
    return counter;
}


int main()
{
    undirected_graph myGraph;
    buildGraph(&myGraph);
    return 0;
}

void buildGraph(undirected_graph * g)
{
    vertex * v1 = new vertex(1);
    vertex * v2 = new vertex(2);

    g->addVertex(v1);           
    g->addVertex(v2);
    g->createEdge(v1,v2);

    std::cout<<"The total number of edges: " << g->getNumberOfEdges();  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `addVertex(vertex * v)`, you add a *copy* of the vertex argument to the list with `graph.push_back(*v)`. Thus the vertex objects have different addresses.

You probably want to store a `std::list<vertex*>` graph and use `graph.push_back(v)`, then.

Comment: Thank you! I finally get it -- I've been assuming that objects in C++ are passed by reference (like in Java.)

Comment: If that was your assumption, why did you bother with pointers at all :-) ? But if you're coming from Java, that explains your usage of `operator new`. Please note that C++ is not garbage collected.